# Send JSON structure with Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, format, retrofit

I want to send this structure of JSON to server using retrofit 2.0

```
{
"quiz_number":6,
"data":[
    {
    "id_question":1,
    "user_answer":1
    },
    {
    "id_question":2,
    "user_answer":0
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {
    "id_question":40,
    "user_answer":1
    }
 ]
}
```

I have 40 questions in total,and i dont know how to put them from sqlite to json,can someone help me please ?

Thank you!

Comment: simple use Gson to convert in json..

Comment: Currently you have data in which format? I mean in which data structure you receive data from Cursor?

Comment: i'm using content provider to get data from database,and the table has this structure 
ID,
QUESTION
 ID_ROW
 ID_QUESTION 
TRUE_ANSWER
USER_ANSWER
ORIGINAL_FILENAME
MIME
IMAGE

i only need user_answer and id_question from this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will require a Pojo for handling Request and Response in Retrofit, I am showing one example, look at it and implement your logic.

**Your Pojo will look like this**

```
  public class Datum {

@SerializedName("id_question")
@Expose
private Integer idQuestion;
@SerializedName("user_answer")
@Expose
private Integer userAnswer;

public Integer getIdQuestion() {
return idQuestion;
}

public void setIdQuestion(Integer idQuestion) {
this.idQuestion = idQuestion;
}

public Integer getUserAnswer() {
return userAnswer;
}

public void setUserAnswer(Integer userAnswer) {
this.userAnswer = userAnswer;
}

}

public class Example {

@SerializedName("quiz_number")
@Expose
private Integer quizNumber;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public Integer getQuizNumber() {
return quizNumber;
}

public void setQuizNumber(Integer quizNumber) {
this.quizNumber = quizNumber;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

I used Jsonschema to create this pojo look at it

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

You have to insert the data from your database into this pojo.

For Complete Reference (Retrofit Example)
https://github.com/pratikvyas1991/NetworkingExample/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: does this creates a JSON structure ? because im new to this and i dont understand it very much

Comment: the json you mentioned in your question that I converted into pojo(Required for Retrofit ) now you have to populate that pojo using query from your database .

Comment: @black_beast you can also refer my shared link for complete Retrofit example